# How to fix read failure on Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, smart

One of my hard drives wasn't working properly when I was trying to install windows 10 on it, so I searched for the error and I checked HD for errors with Smartctl selftests.

I tried some usual fixes like overwriting with zeros the sections with error but it didn't work.

Here's the log of selftest:

```
sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb 

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       828         15353528
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%       827         55762560
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       827         15325464
# 4  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       827         15323008
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       827         15323008
# 6  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%       827         16319388
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%       827         16319388
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       537         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
```

Can I fix these errors or its just unrecoverable?
Let me know if I can provide further information.

#### Hard Drive Info

```
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
Serial Number:    S32SJ5DF211384
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 4013ff254
Firmware Version: 2BA30001
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

#### Smartctl full log

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       29202
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   092   080   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       2643
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1361
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   095   095   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       864
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       846
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1408
 13 Read_Soft_Error_Rate    0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3398445
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       107
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       17299
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   064   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 20/45)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       864
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   095   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       923
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       616
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       822
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   096   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       6322514
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   096   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       6719332
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       828         15353528
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%       827         55762560
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       827         15325464
# 4  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       827         15323008
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       827         15323008
# 6  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%       827         16319388
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%       827         16319388
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       537         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed_read_failure [90% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
```

Comment: Without seeing the complete SMART Data, it's difficult to say for sure. What size drive? Is the drive external, and if so, does it have its own power supply? Edit your question and show me `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb`. **Maybe** we can bad block the drive. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I've edited the question with further information about the drive. It's an internal hard disk, I used to use it for windows but I was planning to use it just for storage. I don't know if it's relevant, but it didn't have so many errors, some of them appeared when I tried to 'zero-out' the sectors with error.

Comment: I've put together an answer that instructs you how to bad block this disk. There are no guarantees. If it fails, or is still unusable, the disk is truly defective. Report back.

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema The scan is still running. 8 hours passed and only 5% done. I'm worried about this.

Comment: It's a 1TB drive, so it WILL take many hours... however, if it's finding a lot of bad blocks... that would explain the 5%. Let it run, if you can.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't recover or repair 'read failures' of this type on SMART tests.  These failures are indicative of device and drive failure, or pre-failure, especially if you actually try and read data off disk and get `Input/Output errors` and such.

You will need to replace the drive.  That's the only way to get past the fact the drive is failing.

Answer (score 4):

To bad block your disk, follow this procedure. If it fails, your disk is bad...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: thanks for the non-dogmatic, helpful response.  Even though I agree completely with Thomas Ward's diagnosis and prescription, your response actually answers the question, and the question I had when I came looking.

Comment: Could you comment on : do not badblock ssd? Do not interrupt badblock ? I did it....

Comment: @jaromrax Because of the way SSDs operate, you'll never really test all of the RAM inside a SSD. If you interrupt a BBS you don't know what you're left with, as the bad block table may not be fully updated. Just follow the instructions and don't do it.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you, I never just follow the instructions :), I am grateful for your clear response.